# How can we save vector layer as a file in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon, point, line, feature-layer

I'm using **MapServer + OpenLayers** for GIS API and I'm new to GIS. I'm done with drawing line, point and polygon features in OpenLayers, but not being able to save it in some shapefile afterwards. I got to display the particular shapefile in map on click event. I have got no idea about how to do it.

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/prerana_liza/8jdz03u1/1/) to see my code

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers runs in the browser, and does not provide a method for generating shapefiles.

What I would suggest is generating GeoJSON of your drawn featurres and POSTing that to the server, where you can use your language of choice to generate a shapefile from the GeoJSON.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just save the edits to your wfs-t? 
If you don't have to use Mapserver you could for example use Geoserver to publish your services and save your edits and users could download the layer directly from Geoserver as shapefiles.

http://www.gistutor.com/openlayers/22-advanced-openlayers-tutorials/47-openlayers-wfs-t-using-a-geoserver-hosted-postgis-layer.html